# how to filter in sql script to not include any column null

Tags: sql, sql-server, scripting

imagine there are 50 columns. I dont wan't any row that includes a null value. Are there any tricky way?

SQL 2005 server

Comment: You don't want any null values in ANY of the 50 columns?

Comment: yeah.. The valid rows must have all columns filled ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's SQL Server 2005+ you can do something like:

```
SELECT fields
FROM MyTable
WHERE stuff
EXCEPT -- This excludes the below results
SELECT fields
FROM MyTable
WHERE (Col1 + Col2 + Col3....) IS NULL
```

Adding a null to a value results in a null, so the sum of all your columns will be `NULL`.
This may need to change based on your data types, but adding `NULL` to either a char/varchar or a number will result in another `NULL`.

Comment: @gbn - Yeah I thought of that too, and added it to the end.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, not really. All 50 columns have to be checked in one form or another.

```
Column1 IS NOT NULL AND ... AND Column50 IS NOT NULL
```

Of course, under these conditions why not disallow NULLs in the first place by having NOT NULL in the table definition

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at the values not being null,  you can do this in the select statement.

SELECT ISNULL(firstname,''), ISNULL(lastname,'') FROM TABLE WHERE SOMETHING=1

This will replace nulls with string blanks.  If you want another value use:  ISNULL(firstname,'empty') for example.  You can use anything where the word empty is.

Comment: I think he wants to not have any rows in his result set where any value is `NULL`.

Answer (score -1):

I prefer this query

```
select *
from table
where column1>''
and column2>''
and (column3>'' or column3<'')
```

Allows sql server to use an index seek if the proper index/es exist.  you would have to do the syntext for column 3 for any numeric values that could be negative.

Comment: ...except any inequality comparison to `NULL` will always return false, since `NULL` is not a value but an absence of a value.  Try `SELECT 'OK' Where 2 > NULL` and see what you get :)

Comment: yes, it always returns false for nulls, but any other value works fine (you could always make it >= to compensate for empty non-null strings), hence getting rid of all records with any nulls.